# Ncurses "mvaddch()" Moves Diagonal

Tags: c, ncurses

I'm trying to create an Etch-n-sketch game and when I move the arrow keys up and down, the cursor moves to the right and in what ever direction I pressed. I can move right, though it appears to be skipping a spot and I cant move left

Code for moving and drawing:

```
void moveCursor(char input)
{
  int cursorX_Pos;
  int cursorY_Pos;
  int arrows;

  getyx(stdscr, cursorY_Pos, cursorX_Pos);

  arrows = 1;
  switch(input)
  {
    case UP:
      cursorY_Pos--;
      arrows = 0;
      break;
    case DOWN:
      cursorY_Pos++;
      arrows = 0;
      break;
    case RIGHT:
      cursorX_Pos++;
      arrows = 0;
      break;
    case LEFT:
      cursorX_Pos--;
      arrows = 0;
      break;
    default:
      arrows = 1;
      break;
  }
  if (arrows == 0)
  {
    draw(cursorY_Pos,cursorX_Pos);
  }
}
void draw(int y, int x)
{
  mvaddch(y, x, '#');
  refresh();
}
```

I'm not really sure where the code is trying to move diagonal. I tried splitting up the mvaddch into move and addch. I tried them at diffrent times and the move works (doesnt appear to be skipping) but when I enable the addch part, it skips and goes diagonal. How do I do fix this?

Comment: You need to provide more code it's impossible to help with what you've provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a character to the screen, the cursor moves to the position after it. So, when you then fetch the current cursor position, it's one cell to the right of where you moved to, before adding the character. Thus, when trying to move left, for instance: you're subtracting 1 in `moveCursor()`, and adding 1 back in `draw()`.

Either subtract 1 from `cursorX_pos` after the `getyx()`, or perhaps, maintain your coordinate values independent of curses' idea of where the cursor is (i.e. just leave out the `getyx()`).

For bonus points, realize that the target coordinates (for the next draw) and the current position are two different things, and optimize accordingly. (Hint: moving right shouldn't require a `move()` at all.)